# How often is the information in the "Users" list updated?

Tags: support

How often is the information at https://askubuntu.com/users updated? Is this something that happens instantaneously, or hourly like the main reputation synching with the meta, or something entirely different? Does the refresh time vary by whether you are looking at the "week", "month", "quarter", or "year" tabs? Explanations will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked with the developers and I'm told the reputation is cached for about 10 minutes.